# Distributive property Question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am determining the rate of change - the expression is $\frac{f(a) - f(1)}{a-1}$

I am stuck at $$\frac{\frac{1}{a} - \frac{1}{1}}{a-1}$$

How, with all steps included, do I arrive at $-\frac{1}{a}$.

I can't see how one utilizes the distributive property. $-\frac{1}{a}$ is the answer in the book. I got $\frac{1}{a^2-a}$.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you edit your post to include parentheses? It's difficult to discern what you mean.

Comment: Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\frac{1}{a} - \frac{1}{1}}{a-1} = \frac{\frac{1}{a} - \frac{a}{a}}{a-1}= \frac{\frac{1-a}{a}}{a-1}=\frac{1-a}{a(a-1)}=\frac{1-a}{-a(1-a)}=-\frac{1}{a}$$

Comment: So in the denominator you never (really) multiply the terms after you flip (reciprocal) the second fraction? Is that a rule?

Comment: Did you also multiply the top and bottom in the forth step by -1? If so, why is 1-a in the numerator not -1+a?

Comment: I'm not sure if I completely understand your question, but in the first three steps I treated the fraction on the numerator as a separate expression (independent manipulation like this is allowed). Also the step between the second to last and last fraction is $\frac{1-a}{-a(1-a)} = \frac{1}{-a} = -\frac{1}{a}$ due to the cancellation of the $1-a$ terms.

Comment: Independent manipulation is allowed? What do you mean by that? Also, the second to last steps are where you lose me. I don't understand how you were able to multiply the entire denominator by a negative (maybe I don't understand the distributive property properly), in  addition to that, you did not do the same for the numerator. Arent you supposed to multiply both the numerator and denominator by the negative sign.

Comment: I factored out a $-1$ out of the denominator, $(a-1) = -(1-a)$.